# bootstrap standard errors of a linear regression in R

Tags: r

I have a lm object and I would like to bootstrap only its standard errors. In practice I want to use only part of the sample (with replacement) at each replication and get a distribution of standard erros. Then, if possible, I would like to display the summary of the original linear regression but with the bootstrapped standard errors and the corresponding p-values (in other words same beta coefficients but different standard errors).

Edited: In summary I want to "modify" my lm object by having the same beta coefficients of the original lm object that I ran on the original data, but having the bootstrapped standard errors (and associated t-stats and p-values) obtained by computing this lm regression several times on different subsamples (with replacement).

So my lm object looks like

```
    Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      3.812793   0.095282  40.016  < 2e-16 ***
x                                -0.904729   0.284243  -3.183  0.00147 ** 
z                                0.599258   0.009593  62.466  < 2e-16 ***
x*z                              0.091511   0.029704   3.081  0.00208 **
```

but the associated standard errors are wrong, and I would like to estimate them by replicating this linear regression 1000 times (replications) on different subsample (with replacement).

Is there a way to do this? can anyone help me?

Thank you for your time.
Marco

Comment: Would you like to bootstrap the standard errors from the `lm` object or from the original data? Please edit **the question** with that important information.

Comment: I want to run the lm object 1000 times on different subsample each time (with replacement) in order to get new standard errors which are going to replace the ones (wrong) in the original lm object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask can be done following the line of the code below.
Since you have not posted an example dataset nor the model to fit, I will use the built in dataset `mtcars` an a simple formula with two continuous predictors.

```
library(boot)

boot_function <- function(data, indices, formula){
  d <- data[indices, ]
  obj <- lm(formula, d)
  coefs <- summary(obj)$coefficients
  coefs[, "Std. Error"]
}

set.seed(8527)

fmla <- as.formula("mpg ~ hp * cyl")
seboot <- boot(mtcars, boot_function, R = 1000, formula = fmla)

colMeans(seboot$t)
##[1] 6.511530646 0.068694001 1.000101450 0.008804784
```

I believe that it is possible to use the code above for most needs with numeric response and predictors.

Comment: Thank you so much Rui you really helped me a lot! What should I put instead of indices? Is it correct to put random rows (e.g. sample(nrow(df),100)) from my dataframe so that each replication will estimate the model by using this subset of the dataframe only?

Comment: In others words I would like to estimate the model by using a subset of observations only, namely to "replace" indices with something like "sample(nrow(df), 300)". Can you just explain where should I specify this please?

Comment: @MarcoMello No! Function `boot` does that on its own. That is the main reason why package `boot` exists. All you have to do is to program a function with `data` and `indices` (or any other names) as **first and second arguments**. In the function, start like my `boot_function` starts, by subsetting `data`. Then you have the instructions to compute the statistic.

Comment: Function `boot::boot` samples the *random rows (e.g. sample(nrow(df),100))*, don't worry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much Rui this works perfectly then, you are very kind to explain all this to me! sorry to bother you for the last small question. Is there a way to specify how many rows to subset? I understood that boot does this on its own, but I do not understand according to what it decides how many obs to use each replication. Probably, according to what you say, it just does this internally by creating every time a different simulated dataset (which is a subset of my original one) and uses this to compute the bootstrapped statistic.

Comment: Ok I probably get it, it creates every time a pseudo-dataframe consisting of the same number of original observations which are individually sampled (with replacement) from the original one. So the number of obs will be the same of the original data for every pseudo-sample. Thank you so much Rui.

Comment: @MarcoMello Yes, it chooses rows at random from the entire dataset. If you want to limit the number of rows, you will have to pass a smaller dataset.

Comment: can this be applied to a plm formula? I would like to bootstrap standard errors  for a 2sls model

Comment: @Bob Yes, it can. But it needs to be adapted to create a `pdata.frame` first.